# Burned motherboard component

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, desktop-computer, intel-core-i7

I got a desktop computer assembled with the following specs:

- 2x 4 GB DDR3
- Intel Core i7-2600 CPU, 3.4 GHz LGA 1155 8 MB Cache
- Intel DH67 BL Media Series motherboard, LGA 1155, 4 slot eSATA, HDMI, USB 3.0
- 1 TB 7200 rpm Seagate drive

The computer ran 24x7 for about 9 months through a UPS. Now, one day, I wake up and find the computer switched off. I tried to turn it on but it wouldn't switch on and there was a burning smell. When I toggled the power supply from the back of the SMPS, it did turn on and reached the Windows boot screen. However, on selecting "Boot windows normally", it turned off immediately. On opening the case, I noticed that after switching on the PC, the CPU, SMPS and cabinet fans turn on for a couple of seconds and then turn off automatically and restart again. There is no display on the monitor.

I showed it to a mechanic; he showed a burned component on the motherboard:

[image: picture]
[image: picture]

1. Do you think the burned component would require me to get a new motherboard?
2. In case I have to replace the motherboard, how can I tell which motherboards are compatible with a given CPU?

Comment: I've edited you second question out, since the [faq] classifies shopping recommendations as off topic.

Comment: Even if you could determine what the part should be replaced with, do you even have the skills, to replace it?

Comment: I replaced the motherboard with a new GIGABYTE motherboard. PC is working fine again. Intel (New Delhi India) refused to take in the motherboard saying that the burned component was my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to replace the motherboard.

According to the information you've given, you have an INTEL I7 2600 3.4GHZ with a 1155 socket. On Intel's site is a [list of compatible motherboards](http://processormatch.intel.com/CompDB/SearchResult.aspx?ProcNbr=i7-2600) for that processor.

[image]

Yours is the last one listed under Media Series, DH67BL.

Answer (score 1):

1. Probably. But it's hard to tell because your picture is in so close.
2. If you gather information about what CPU you have and what devices you need to connect to it (How many drives? What kind? Are you using a discrete graphics card? And so on.) then it's just a matter of comparing specifications. If you're lazy, just grab a [direct replacement](http://www.aztekcomputers.com/DH67BLBULK-INTEL-3789969.html).

What, if anything, was connected to the `FP USB 3` header? The component that failed is a 1.6A polyfuse on the USB power connector. Did the USB port short, perhaps? Polyfuses are supposed to self-heal, but that one certainly won't!

Comment: Thanks David. I added another pic. Nothing was connected to the FP USB 3 header. It was connected to the usb ports in the front of the cabinet but the front usb ports have never worked. CPU is "CPU INTEL I7 2600 3.4GHZ 1155 8MB Cache". One 1TB SATA drive. No graphics card.

Comment: It looks like you could use pretty much any motherboard that supports that CPU. You might be able to clean the area around the burned polyfuse and just not use that USB header. But it's a bit scary -- who knows what damage was done by the excessive current flow that burned up that fuse.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think the burned component would require me to get a new
>   motherboard?

Yes, a replacment is needed.

> In case I have to replace the motherboard, how can I tell which
>   motherboards are compatible with a given CPU?

I would first suggest that you try to utilize any warranty process that intel or the builder (if it was not you who built it) to be exausted first. If the board is 9 months old, there should be some protection to you before having to go and buy one out of pocket. This link to[Intel warranty and service](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-009050.htm) site may give you some info and contacts to get started.

Or contact the builder and they may need to process the RMA.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the motherboard.  You have solder that has leaked onto other components and burn marks that cover traces that look like they go to the PCI expansion slot, which is connected to the PCI bus.  Since motherboards are many PCBs layered together, there could very well be damage to traces that are not visible.

If the motherboard is under warranty, then definitely send it back.  Otherwise, it would just be easier to replace it.

Comment: Got it. It is under warranty but I have been told that the local Intel service center doesn't accept motherboards with burned components.

Comment: @user674669 don't tell them it's "burned". When you say that, they get them impression that it was in a fire. Just tell them it doesn't work.  _This is a manufacturing flaw and should be covered by the warranty._

Comment: Dont believe what you hear.  Since you were using a UPS, this definitely points to a manufacturing flaw.  They *better* take it back.